# Creating a tree with LINQ expression

Tags: c#, linq, multidimensional-array

I have a C# List of following fields which are returned by a stored procedure:

```
CarrierId   ParentCarrierId Name Descrition
1            NULL            A         AA
2              1             B         BB
3              1             C         CC
4              3             D         DD
5            NULL            E         EE
```

I need to construct a nested object list out of this output

So each object of Carrier should have list of all it's children. Can anyone help me construct a LINQ code to accomplish this?

Desired Result:

```
 CarrierId = 1
      |__________________ CarrierId = 2
      |__________________ CarrierId = 3
                              |___________________ CarrierId = 4

 CarrierId = 5
```

Desired result should be as mentioned above

Comment: How many rows in the table, can it be Linq-To-Objects? If not, what LINQ provider are you using?

Comment: This is the output returned by stored proc and in the form of List<Carrier>

Comment: How deep can it be, only one level or unlimited?

Comment: There is no limit but mostly it's not more than 3 levels. Need to treat it as N levels

Answer (score 3):

First create a lookup that maps a parent ID to its children:

```
var lookup = carriers.ToLookup(carrier => carrier.ParentCarrierId);
```

The go through each node and assign its children based on the lookup:

```
foreach(var carrier in carriers)
    carrier.Children = lookup[carrier.CarrierId];
```

To get all of the root nodes just get the null values from the lookup:

```
var roots = lookup[null];
```

Note that this entire operation is O(n), as building the lookup is O(n) and all of the children for every single carrier can be found in O(n) time, rather than taking O(n^2) time as in the other solutions posted (as they use an O(n) operation to find all of the children for a *single* node).  This makes this code dramatically faster than the other options, in addition to being much simpler and shorter.

Comment: Since `CarrierId` is the primary key you are mapping each carrier to itself.

Comment: @TimSchmelter is right. When you create the loopup table, you have to provide `carrier.ParentCarrierId` as the lookup key. Apart from that mistake, it's a really nice solution, though.

Comment: The approach is more efficient but i think most have misunderstood the requirement. OP doesn't want to get all carriers which are below the parent but only the children. That's trivial.

Comment: @TimSchmelter This gets all of the direct decedents of each item and assigns them as the children of that item.  Doing so creates a tree structure identical to the one described in the question.

Comment: Also, to make this answer even better, I suggest renaming `lookup` to something more meaningful like `childrenOf`.

Comment: @Abbondanza Creation of the tree should be in its own method, so there should only be these three lines of text there.  It's not like there are other lookups that it could be confused with there.  And note that "childrenOf" isn't a description of what that object *is*, its a description of what it can do.  What it *is* is a lookup.  If it needed to be distinguished from other kinds of lookups then a `parentChildLookup` or `relationshipLookup` could be used, but, as mentioned earlier, the variable shouldn't be in a position to require that.

Comment: @Servy, that it is lookup is clear from the object's type signature and the fact that it is created with `ToLookup()`. The type of a variable shouldn't be part of its name. I just believe your perfectly good answer is better to understand for novices, if the symbol names express their intent, not their type. Whether the intent is expressed in terms of a symbol's defining property or how it can be acted upon, is secondary.

Answer (score 1):

Your original question was a little bit different. I thought that each carrier should hold a list of all of it's descendents. Now it seems that you only want to hold all direct children. That's simple:

```
c.Children = carrierList.Where(child => child.ParentCarrierId == c.CarrierId).ToList();
```

If you want it as LINQ query then you have to create new instances of `Carrier`:

```
List<Carrier> rootCarriers = carrierList
    .Select(c => new Carrier { 
        CarrierId = c.CarrierId,
        Name = c.Name,
        Descrition = c.Descrition,
        ParentCarrierId = c.ParentCarrierId,
        Children = carrierList
            .Where(child => child.ParentCarrierId == c.CarrierId)
            .ToList()
    })
    .Where(c => !c.ParentCarrierId.HasValue)
    .ToList();
```

That query also removes all which are not root-carriers(have parents) as desired.

Following shows both approaches in two different properties `Children` and `Descendants`, the latter returns even grandchildren and so on.

```
public class Carrier
{
    public List<Carrier> Descendants { get; set; }
    public List<Carrier> Children { get; set; }

    public static IEnumerable<Carrier> TraverseDescendants(IEnumerable<Carrier> allCarriers, Carrier rootCarrier)
    {
        Queue<Carrier> queue = new Queue<Carrier>();
        var children = allCarriers.Where(c => c.ParentCarrierId == rootCarrier.CarrierId);
        foreach (Carrier c in children)
            queue.Enqueue(c);
        while (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            Carrier child = queue.Dequeue();
            yield return child;
            var grandchildren = allCarriers.Where(c => c.ParentCarrierId == child.CarrierId);
            foreach (Carrier c in grandchildren)
                queue.Enqueue(c);
        }
    }
}
```

With the `TraverseDescendents` you can initialize the `List<Carrier> Descendents` in your class. The `Children`-list is a trivial LINQ query:

```
foreach (Carrier c in carrierList)
{
    c.Descendants = Carrier.TraverseDescendants(carrierList, c).ToList();
    c.Children = carrierList.Where(child => child.ParentCarrierId == c.CarrierId).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I don't have a specific root

Comment: TraverseChildren method takes RootCarrier as second parameter. My List is unsorted and there can be more than one carriers without any child

Comment: @InTheWorldOfCodingApplications: it doesnt need to be sorted. Haven't you seen how i loop all carriers in the list? `TraverseChildren` gives you all children of a specifc `Carrier`. I thought that this was what you wanted since your question contains: _"each object of Carrier should have list of all it's children"_

Comment: (IEnumerable<Carrier> allCarriers, Carrier rootCarrier) what would be passed as root carrier then?

Comment: @InTheWorldOfCodingApplications: look at the working sample code below the method. Root can be any carrier, even those without children. It just means that this is the carrier you want all children from.

Comment: This works to the entext that objects are getting in heirarchical order but the flat list have 50 objects of carrier and after applying this method it still has 50 with children added

Comment: @InTheWorldOfCodingApplications: yes, and what is the desired result? Your requirement was _"So each object of Carrier should have list of all it's children"_ Maybe it would help to provide a desired result in your question. My solution provides a way to get all carrier's children.

Comment: Can we modify this to arrange List<carrier> in purely heirarchical way i-e each object should only appear once

Comment: @InTheWorldOfCodingApplications: i have no idea what you're trying to achieve. Please provide the desired result in your question.

Comment: I have updated the question to elaborate the end desired result

Comment: @InTheWorldOfCodingApplications: but what kind of collection is this "hierarchical way"? Since every `Carrier` holds a list of it's children you can even now traverse the children down the road with my approach. So the `List<Carrier>` contains all carrier-children flattened, but if you want to go down to the grandchild and so on you just need to look at the children's `Children` property.

Comment: I'll take your example: if you have carrier with id=1 the `Children` property returns a `List<Carrier>` with three carriers with ID's 2, 3 and 4. But if you look at the first carrier in the list which is carrier2 and it's `Children` property it only contains one carrier which is carrier4, the grandchild of carrier1. Do you want that carrier1 contains only 2 and 3 and not 4 so only the direct ancestor?

Comment: what i am struggling to achieve is CarrierId=1 should have CarrierId=2 and CarrierId=3 as children and CarrierId=3 would have CarrierId=4 as Child. In purely nested way

Comment: @InTheWorldOfCodingApplications: updated my answer to provide both approaches

Comment: this still returns the all objects not the nested structure. Sorry i am missing something

Comment: @InTheWorldOfCodingApplications: if i test it `Children` now only contains the direct children whereas `Descendants` contains even grandchildren or even deeper.

Comment: This is being done on the flattFile structure which has say 50 objects. After applying your login the flatfile still have 50 objects with nested structure. How can we avoid that?

Comment: @InTheWorldOfCodingApplications: so you want to remove all objects from the list which are not "root" carriers? Or you want to create a new list which only contains carriers which are not "roots"?

Comment: Need to remove which are not root as they will appear as nested object somewhere on the list as Children. SO basically end result should be a purely nested thing

Comment: @InTheWorldOfCodingApplications: however, you just need to append: `List<Carrier> rootCarriers = carrierList.Where(c => !c.ParentCarrierId.HasValue).ToList();` (presuming that `ParentCarrierId` is an `int?`)

Comment: Will this remove a carrier if it does not have a Parent?

Comment: No, it will only leave the top-parents in the list, `!c.ParentCarrierId.HasValue` means all which don't have a `ParentCarrierId`. You still have the `Children` if the property was initialized in the loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96174/discussion-between-intheworldofcodingapplications-and-tim-schmelter).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IList<Carrier> CarrierList = new List<Carrier>();
            CarrierList.Add(new Carrier { CarrierId = 1, Name = "A", Description = "AA", ParentCarrierId = null });
            CarrierList.Add(new Carrier { CarrierId = 2, Name = "B", Description = "BB", ParentCarrierId = 1 });
            CarrierList.Add(new Carrier { CarrierId = 3, Name = "C", Description = "CC", ParentCarrierId = 1 });
            CarrierList.Add(new Carrier { CarrierId = 4, Name = "D", Description = "DD", ParentCarrierId = 3 });
            CarrierList.Add(new Carrier { CarrierId = 5, Name = "E", Description = "EE", ParentCarrierId = null });
            Temp temp = new Temp();
        IList<Carrier> CarrierList1=new List<Carrier>(); 
             foreach (Carrier carrier in CarrierList.Where(p => p.ParentCarrierId == null).ToList() )
            {
                CarrierList1.Add(temp.Recursive(carrier, CarrierList));
            }
        }
    }
    public class Temp
    {
        public Carrier Recursive(Carrier carrier,IList<Carrier> carrierList)
        {

            if (carrierList.Where(c => c.ParentCarrierId == carrier.CarrierId).Count() <1)
            {
                return carrier ;
            }
            else
            {
                IList<Carrier> newList = new List<Carrier>();
                foreach (Carrier ca in carrierList.Where(c => c.ParentCarrierId == carrier.CarrierId)){
                    newList.Add(Recursive(ca, carrierList));
            }
                carrier.CarrierList = newList;
                return carrier;
            }
        }
    }
    public class Carrier
    {
        public int CarrierId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int? ParentCarrierId { get; set; }
        public IList<Carrier> CarrierList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work against an in-memory ienumerable of carriers if you add a 
`public List<Carrier> Children { get; set; }` property to your Carrier-class.

```
public static class CarrierExt
{

    public static List<Carrier> AsTree(this IEnumerable<Carrier> carriers)
    {
        return carriers.AsTree(null);
    }

    private static List<Carrier> AsTree(this IEnumerable<Carrier> carriers, int? parentId)
    {
        return (from carrier in carriers
                where carrier.ParentCarrierId == parentId
                let children = carrier.Children = carriers.AsTree(carrier.CarrierId)
                select carrier).ToList();
    }
}
```

edit: note that this will reduce the top level list to only the 2 root elements.